# why iphone "text to speech" english is much clearer than french?

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech

after config in “Settings>General>Accessibility>Speak”, i could select a paragraph of text then could let iphone "speek" it out. But I found that French text are spoken much vaguely, on the contrary, English are much more clearly read out. Is there a way to improve French text speek effect?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried other french boices?

[image]

Comment: I tried. but it's very strange, that Audrey is very fast...